# Tiger API Soap request. Highly confusing

Tags: php, api, soap

I'm at the beginning of setting up the Tiger Air API. They have given few URLs for testing but these doesn't seem to work. Following are the details I received from them

### Contact mail:

For testing, we have linked this account to your

```
xxxxxx agency in TEST (currency SGD).
Username: xxx
P/W: xxx (password will have to be changed on first login)
Domain: xxx
RoleCode: xxx
```

The URL’s for the API to test for connectivity are as follows:

Test: https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/sessionmanager.svc

For the access to the various services, you will want to make your calls to the following DNS:

Test: https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com

### SOAP sample request

The above two URLs don't seem to work at all. Its surprising that they did not provide the WSDL url. I have got the sample request from them.

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:web="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices" 
    xmlns:ses="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService" 
    xmlns:ses1="http://schemas.navitaire.com/WebServices/DataContracts/Session"
>
    <soapenv:Header>
        <web:ContractVersion>320</web:ContractVersion>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ses:LogonRequest>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ses:logonRequestData>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ses1:DomainCode>EXT</ses1:DomainCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ses1:AgentName>MyAgent</ses1:AgentName>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ses1:Password>P@ssword</ses1:Password>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ses1:LocationCode></ses1:LocationCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ses1:RoleCode></ses1:RoleCode>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <ses1:TerminalInfo></ses1:TerminalInfo>
            </ses:logonRequestData>
        </ses:LogonRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I was struggling for a long time trying to figure out the basic setup but going into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

your server ip need to be allowed for requests on this link

```
<?
$Username = 'xxx';
$Password: 'xxx';
$Domain: 'xxx';

$url = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
$params = array(
    'logonRequestData' => array(
        'DomainCode' => $Domain,
        'AgentName' => $Username,
        'Password' => $Password,
    )
);

print_r($client->Logon($params));
?>
```

another useful code

```
<?
$url = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/SessionManager.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($client->__getTypes());
?>
```

and

```
<?
$url = "https://trtestr3xapi.navitaire.com/BookingManager.svc?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url);
print_r($client->__getFunctions());
print_r($client->__getTypes());
?>
```

Comment: I get this error

    Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php(28): SoapClient->__call('Logon', Array) #1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php(28): SoapClient->Logon(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\ezyflying.com\tiger\index.php on line 28

Comment: You can't pass an array of values. It needs an object (LogonRequestData) with the values.